# Child div positioning css

Tags: css, position

I want to position #inner2 and #inner3 divs to float side by side. And to full fit #outer div as in case the browser window size changes.
inner3 is not floating well as i want it to. It is overlapping.

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">...</div>
  <div id="inner2">
     <asp:image .. src="some.jpg" cssClass="img"/>
  </div>
  <div id="inner3">
     //...
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#inner2{
    position:relative;
    width:25%;
    padding-bottom:25%;
    float:left;
    height:0;
}
.img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
#inner3 {
    padding: 13px;
    width:70%;
    height:170px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    float:left;   
}
```

Comment: you should remove  `position:absolute`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#inner2{
    width:25%;
    padding-bottom:25%;
    float:left;
    height:0;
}
.img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.inner3 {
    padding: 13px;
    width:70%;
    height:170px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:left;   
}
```

this should be your css

and if they aren't next to eachother that means your padding and margin is more than the 5% width of total width, so reduce them.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code a bit to make it much more easy to understand the principles.
Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stassel/j207xp0q/1/)

Basically both #inner elements (2 and 3) must be displayed as blocks and than you just float the left one to the left and the right one to the right:

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">1</div>
  <div id="inner2">2</div>
  <div id="inner3">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
  background-color:#d2d2d2;
  width:100%;
}
#inner1, #inner2, #inner3 {
  display:block;
}
#inner2{
  height:170px;
  width:24%;
  float:left;
  background-color:rgba(170,120,50,0.5);
}
#inner3 {
  width:74%;
  height:170px;
  float:right;
  background-color:rgba(120,140,150,0.5);
}
```